# Linux Python Scripts to get hardware complete details like serial number ,brand , model, cpu info

Tags: python, linux, centos

I have been tried to get linux centos 7 hardware details in python 3 . but i have got only minimal details, need to get all the hardware details like brand name , model, serial number , manufacturer deatils in centos 7 . And need to get installed software details like application name , installed date , installed location

I have googled lots of time but i have not got the exact answers

Comment: Since Stack Overflow is not a script writing service, you will have to show us, what you have tried so far (your code) and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install psutil, then you can add whatever you want

```
import psutil

cpu = 'CPU: ' + str(psutil.cpu_percent()) + '%\n'

ram = dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())
ram_total = round(ram['total'] / 1073741824, 2)
answer = f"RAM total: {ram_total}Gb\n"
ram_used = round(ram['used'] / 1073741824, 2)
answer += f"RAM used: {ram_used}Gb ({ram['percent']}%)\n"
ram_free = round(ram['free'] / 1073741824, 2)
answer += f"RAM free: {ram_free}Gb\n"
ram_available = round(ram['available'] / 1073741824, 2)
answer += f"RAM available: {ram_available}Gb\n"

disk = dict(psutil.disk_usage('/')._asdict())
disk_used = round(disk['used'] / 1073741824, 2)
ssd = f"SSD used: {disk_used}Gb ({disk['percent']}%)\n"

print(cpu)
print(answer)
print(ssd)
```